# How to Pivot data in Vaadin

Tags: java, gwt, web, vaadin

Has anyone come across a **Vaadin** component that will allow users to pivot data, thus they can provide the dimensions and the measurements.

Does there such a component/widget exists in vaadin ?

Comment: What do you mean by pivot data ?
For a client we did just place 3 fields side-by-side so they could enter with/height/lenght

Comment: as you you have a database tables with a mixture of Strings and Numbers. the user is presented with a the available fields and creates a pivot ( possibly also know as a cross tab) of the data. Nothing to do with Width/Height of cells.

Comment: I have not used Vaadin, because according to the Vaadin Book, probably you can create a custom component to do that. Check this out: https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable, and then try to develop the Vaadin Component. Regards!

Comment: @camikiller There is a Vaadin Wrapper for the PivotTable from Nicolas Kruchten here: https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/pivottable

But this pivot grid isn't good enough for OLAP use... i'm looking for a Vaadin OLAP component too.